# Debugging an exception, source information missing

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012

My program seems to run for a short time before crashing with the following error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x001FFF23 in Program.exe: 0xC0000005: 
Access violation reading location 0x040FA010.
```

The call stack is very unhelpful (Source information is missing from the debug information for this module), so I have no idea where the problem is. The program runs normally for a varying amount of time before crashing (several hundred frames), so locating the problem using breakpoints is very difficult. Tried loading symbols but no symbols were found.

```
ntdll.dll!_NtRaiseException@12()   Unknown
ntdll.dll!_KiUserExceptionDispatcher@8()   Unknown
0027ff23()  Unknown
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing]  
nvoglv32.dll!582c9af4() Unknown
nvoglv32.dll!582c9dbb() Unknown
nvoglv32.dll!582cdbd3() Unknown
nvoglv32.dll!582d0918() Unknown
nvoglv32.dll!57a9491b() Unknown
nvoglv32.dll!580c5f35() Unknown
KernelBase.dll!_GlobalAlloc@8()    Unknown
nvoglv32.dll!57a058a5() Unknown
nvoglv32.dll!579f60ab() Unknown
nvoglv32.dll!582df7ce() Unknown
nvoglv32.dll!57a106e5() Unknown
nvoglv32.dll!58190f2d() Unknown
nvoglv32.dll!582bb8c7() Unknown
nvoglv32.dll!57a0b621() Unknown
nvoglv32.dll!5823285b() Unknown
nvoglv32.dll!58232a9d() Unknown
KernelBase.dll!_HeapCreate@12()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!_NtFreeVirtualMemory@16()    Unknown
KernelBase.dll!_GlobalFree@4() Unknown
```

Looking at the callstack I presume it is something OpenGL related, however glGetError() never indicates a problem. My program is rather long, so I did not post it here. Besides, my problem is not fixing just this particular exception, but finding an efficient way to debug them in the future. Reading through the entire program line by line is not one, as I have no idea in which function the problem occurs. No compiler warnings with /W3, so I have no idea where to begin. How can I find out where an exception exactly occurs in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate?

Comment: Do you have `Debug -> Exceptions... -> Win32 Exceptions -> Access violation` option enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of a GL crash like this is improper buffer handling.  You wouldn't see this surface with glGetError() - the driver would simply crash upon accessing the bad vertex/index buffers.  You might have luck debugging it with [gDEBugger](http://www.gremedy.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Microsoft Symbol Servers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503) to download the symbols for the Windows DLLs.  This will hopefully give you a much better idea of where the error is occurring.  To use the symbol servers with Visual Studio, follow [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: nvoglv32 is the openGL module for some nVidia graphics driver, and I suspect you'd have to go through nVidia to get useful debugging info about it.  A quick google search isn't yielding anything for it though, chances are the symbols are not publicly available (or maybe very expensive).